# Confusion with bootstrap structure(wrapper)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am confused with the Bootstrap structure.

here is the structure:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
First Row, One Column
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
First Row, One Column
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
Second Row, One column
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
Second Row, One column
</div>
</div>
```

There will be issue with margin, padding right? What is the best solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You had missing closing tags (proper code below). In regards to your question, There will be padding and margins because your code is within the container, I would not count that as a issue. Unless i`m missing something.

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    First Row, One Column
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
    First Row, One Column
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    Second Row, One column
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
    Second Row, One column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```